# HTML textarea value is not getting from js in running time

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I don't have too much experience working to JS but I am trying to get the value from textarea using JS when I am writing into textarea but it is not working the append function.

In HTML:

```
<textarea required="" name="wall_post_text" id="wall_post_text" placeholder="Write something...">  </textarea>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.tag_system_search_people', function() {
            var username = $(this).attr('data-people_username');
            var user = $(this).attr('data-people');
            var content = $('#wall_post_text').val();

            content = content.replace(/@(\w+)/ig,'');
            $('#wall_post_text').val(content);
            $('#wall_post_text').append(" <span data-people='"+user+"' data-people_tagged='"+username+"' class='people_tagged' contenteditable='false'>"+username+"</span> ");
alert($('#wall_post_text').val());
            $('#pg_social form#wall_post) 
        });
```

The alert is printing but text without the text in append function.

Comment: last line with $ seems incomplete here.... (no closing parenthesis)

Comment: textarea element requires `.html` or `.text` i think. But as @Pierre mention, script will fail regardless

Comment: You need close tag at this line => $('#pg_social form#wall_post

Comment: @GetSet not true, Use `val()` with a textarea

Comment: I didnt know that @RoryMcCrossan ... makes sense though. Upvoting you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , please could comment about the append function? it is not working. thanks

Comment: You cant use append on a text area. You have to use val()

Comment: but  $('#wall_post_text').append( ....) is not appending, something is wrong?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I tried with val() but when I click in the functtion the textarea is showing : "text + <span data-people= ..... </span>" but i think is not good to show to these html tags a to users.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I want to do like stackoverflow, I use @ (in textarea) to find a user and select it, and print it to textarea but without the html tags in it. Please advise.

Comment: You cannot put HTML in a textarea. The SO textarea just appends text, it doesn't put any HTML in the element. The '@' lookup is a HTML element which is displayed outside the textarea

Comment: yes, i have it in other html with the function $(document).on('click', 'li.tag_system_search_people', function() as in the code above. I changed to:  $('#wall_post_text').val( content + " <span data-people='"+user+"' data-people_tagged='"+username+"' class='people_tagged' contenteditable='false'>"+username+"</span> "); and it is printing html tags in textarea. how to hide this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it right.

For example:

```js
// find elements
$('.elm_submit').on('click', function() {
    /*var username = $(this).attr('data-people_username');
    var user = $(this).attr('data-people');*/
    
    // its value (You can too insert html in variable).
    var content = $('#wall_post_text').val();
    
    // insert value in div
    $('.content').html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Value -->
<textarea required="" name="wall_post_text" id="wall_post_text" placeholder="Write something...">  </textarea>

<!-- Get element --> 
<div class="content">

</div>

<!-- Fire -->
<button class="elm_submit">
Click
</button>
```

and your postcode is incomplete
...

```
    $('#pg_social form#wall_post ... <-
});
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response, and it is rigth, when i copy/paste i lost the some piece of code, my question is about the append function.

Comment: actually, my question was about how to use append function. I am trying to insert into <textarea> </textarea> the some <span> </span> content. thanks

Comment: That's not possible. You cannot put HTML inside a textarea

Comment: That's not possible insert span in textarea!